# How to use Preact signals with astro to share state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact, astrojs

**Problem**
When i change the tag value it only changes on the select component but not in the index.astro

I have folder signals where i export signal

```
export const tagSignal = signal<string>("all");
```

I use it like this  in Select.tsx component, and here evryting changes

```
import { tagSignal } from "@signal/*";
const setTagValue = (value: string) => {
  tagSignal.value = value;
  console.log("select", tagSignal.value);
};

export const Select = () => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = useState("all"); // this will be change to only signals still under refator
  setTagValue(selectedName);
 -------
 ------
```

but when I import it to index.astro like this I get only "all" value witch is inital value

```
---
import { Icon } from "astro-icon";
import { Picture } from "astro-imagetools/components";

import Layout from "@layouts/Layout.astro";
import { Select } from "@components/Select";
import Card from "@components/Card.astro";

import { getCollection } from "astro:content";
import { getProjectsByTag } from "@utils/*";
import { tagSignal } from "@signal/*";

const projects = await getCollection("projects");

const filteredProjects = getProjectsByTag(projects, tagSignal.value);
// TODO: add links

console.log("index", tagSignal.value);
---
/// some code here
 <section id="projects" class="projects">
      <Select client:only="preact" />
      <div class="projects-wrapper">
        {
          filteredProjects.map(({ data: { title, heroImage } }) => (
            <Card name={title} bg_path={heroImage} />
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </section>
---
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here.

1. You are depending on dynamic JS variables in an `.astro` file. It doesn't work the way you are expecting—all the javascript in `.astro` files, with the exception of the "islands," e.g., your `Select.tsx` component, is being evaluated when the page is being built. So Astro grabs the initial value of `tagSignal`, but makes it a static string.

People can get bitten by, e.g., the trivial `©2010—{new Date().getFullYear()}` in the footer – it won't magically update on the new year's eve if used in `.astro` file.

2. The state (signal's current value) is not shared accross the islands. If you want to share it, you need either a global state solution (I haven't used it in Astro yet), or just create a common parent for the `Select` and the filtering logic, e.g.:

```
{/* the signal will be declared (or imported) in `DynamicSection`*/}
<DynamicSection client:only="preact">
    <Select />
    <div class="projects-wrapper">
      {
        filteredProjects.map(({ data: { title, heroImage } }) => (
          <Card name={title} bg_path={heroImage} />
        ))
      }
    </div>
</ DynamicSection>
```

(The simplest global state solution would be probably using the url with a query string, and derive the state from its value).

Comment: Thank you so much I switched to nanostores to  handle this problme and it help but thanks for the suggestions